# how to rescue super key in mintty

Tags: windows, emacs, cygwin, mintty

Lately I intend to use Emacs in Cygwin with mintty, because I found mintty can represent 256 color perfectly. However, the super(win) key seems not to be working in mintty and some other combine-key bindings (like `M-p`, `M-n` in minibuffer) do not work.

How can i solve this problem? Please give me some advice, thank you in advance.

Comment: @Dualinity thanks for your correcting, I have learned a lot from it. Thank you

Comment: You're welcome, sadly do not know mintty so...